# Datalab "deploy" fails

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

On the first step, after clicking "Deploy" button at https://datalab.cloud.google.com/ the messages pops up

> The request to deploy Cloud Datalab into project ... failed.
>
> Please ensure that the project is enabled for billing. Additionally,
>   you must be an owner or editor within the project.
>
> Occasionally, a deployment request may fail due to transient errors or
>   capacity reasons. If so, please try again.

Double checked - billing is enabled (other services work) and I'm the owner of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have the Google Compute Engine APIs enabled (or you didn't wait long enough after enabling them).

Follow the instructions from [Getting Started page](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started) and where it says `Click to: Enable the Google Compute Engine API` click there and select the project to enable it on then click `Enable`. You'll need to wait 15+ minutes after enabling it for it to take effect.

When it's enabled correctly you should see the "Create Instance" screen at https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?project=YOUR_PROJECT